# 64 bits Operation Codes

Tags: assembly, x86-64, opcode

My question is:

Instruction MOV RBX, RCX is compiled+linked by YASM+LINK as: 
**48h 89h CBh**

But inside other programs like notepad.exe (64 bits), the same MOV RBX, RCX appears as: **48h 8Bh D9h**.

Both operation codes are right? Or any error over there? Or what is going on?
Thanks for reading. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct.

`48h 89h CBh` corresponds to `REX.W + 89 /r`, which is `MOV r/m64,r64`

`48h 8Bh D9h` corresponds to `REX.W + 8B /r`, which is `MOV r64,r/m64`

As `RBX` and `RCX` are (64-bit) registers, they match both `r64` and `r/m64`. So either of those encodings could be used.

- `REX.W` means a REX prefix where the `W` bit (64-bit operand size override) is set. The REX prefixes start at 40h, and the `W` bit is bit 3, so that's 40h + 8 == 48h.
- 89h/8Bh is the opcode.
- `/r` is something you'll have to look up in the table named *"Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte"* in Intel's manual. You've got your `r`-operands at the top, and the `r/m`-operands at the left. So if we take `D9h` we see that the `r64` should be `RBX` (the table doesn't list `RBX`, but you've got a 64-bit operand size override), and the `r/m64` should be `RCX`.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael!! Many thanks for your explanation. I think it's clear now.